# How to access application.yml file from the spock test framework

Tags: spock

I have integration tests being configured for a spring boot application which interacts with downstream services. I would like to configure some of the variables used in the `spock` tests from the `application.yml` that is used in the spring application. Is this possible in `Spock` and `groovy`.

I have tried using `Spring` annotations to capture the data as its done in the `Spring` application.

I have tried using the below code but it always is null.

```
@Value('test.base.url')
def variableName
```

I also tried to pointing to the `application.yml` using the `@PropertySource('classpath:application.yml')`

```
package com.company.package1

import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
class GetVariableTests extends Specification {

    @Value('test.base.url')
    def variableName

    def "test variable name"() {
        then:
            variableName == "http://localhost:8020/"
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
test:
   base:
       url:"http://localhost:8020/"
```

I would want this test to pass. However the `variableName` is always null.

Comment: Your Spec looks incomplete, a single `then:` block is not a valid test for spock. If you want something like that you need `expect:`. Also this looks like a Spring Boot project, if so you should use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`. Also make sure you have the `spock-spring` dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to make it work with the @SpringBootTest and the spock-spring dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Spec looks incomplete, a single `then:` block is not a valid test for Spock. 
If you want something like that you need `expect:`.

Also this looks like a Spring Boot project, if so you should use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`. Also make sure you have the `spock-spring` dependency.